# Custom SpringBatch ItemReader, that read form JPA repository using custom query

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-batch

I am new to Spring Batch and I would like to seek the advice of the experienced programmer on how to implement the following:

I am writing an API that triggers a batch task to generate a report from a list of transactions from JPA repo.

In spring batch, there is ItemReader, ItemProcessor, ItemWriter for each step.

How should I implement my ItemReader such that it can execute the following:

1. Generate a custom query from the parameters set in the jobParameters (obtained from the API query)
2. Using the custom query in 2 to obtain the list of transactions from the Transactions JPA repo, which will be processed in the ItemProcessor and subsequently generate reports through ItemWriter.

Question: How should I write the ItemReader, I looking at JpaCursorItemReader (dk if it is the right one) but could not find examples of implementation online to refer to. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

I am at the stage of trying to understand how Spring batch works, I hope to seek proper guidance from experts in this field of the direction to go to accomplished the mentioned task.

Answer (score 0):

> Generate a custom query from the parameters set in the jobParameters (obtained from the API query)

You can define a step-scoped bean and inject job parameters to use them in your query:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public JpaCursorItemReader jpaCursorItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['parameter']}") String parameter) {
    return new JpaCursorItemReaderBuilder()
            .queryString("..") // use job parameter in your query here
            // set other properties on the item reader
            .build();
}
```

You can find more details on step-scoped components in the documentation here: [Late Binding of Job and Step Attributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#late-binding).